# помогите оптимизировать мой код

Tags: python, оптимизация, requests, beautiful-soup

Я сделал код который по `id` участника вернёт словарь, где ключами является `n` репутации, а значение количество ответов имеющие такое количество репутации

Для некоторых пользователей у которых большое количество ответов программа выполняется долго, как это исправить?
как его можно оптимизировать?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

def get_count(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BS(page.text, "html.parser")
    
    pages = soup.find_all("a", class_ = "s-pagination--item")
    return int(max(pages, key = lambda x: int(x.text) if x.text.isdigit() else -1).text)

def get_rep(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BS(page.text, "html.parser")
    
    votes = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "answer-votes")
    
    return map(lambda x: int(x.text.strip()), votes)

id = "2"
url = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/" + id + "?tab=answers&sort=newest&page={}"

dict_ = {}
count = get_count(url.format(0))

for i in range(1, count + 1):
    
    for rep in get_rep(url.format(i)):
        if rep in dict_:
            dict_[rep] += 1
        else:
            dict_[rep] = 1
    print("\033[H\033[J")
    for key, value in sorted(list(dict_.items()), reverse = True):
        print(f"{key}: {value}"
```

Comment: А по какому критерию вы хотите оптимизировать свой код? И главное - зачем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как то вот так попробуйте, только ***не удивляйтесь если ваш IP заблокируют на SO***

```py
from multiprocessing import get_context


def get_count(url):
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = Soup(page.text, "html.parser")

    pages = soup.find_all("a", class_="s-pagination--item")
    return int(max(pages, key=lambda x: int(x.text) if x.text.isdigit() else -1).text)


def get_rep(url_):
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
    page = requests.get(url_)
    soup = Soup(page.text, "html.parser")

    votes = soup.find_all("div", class_="answer-votes")

    return [*map(lambda x: int(x.text.strip()), votes)]


id_ = "2"
url = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/" + id_ + "?tab=answers&sort=newest&page={}"

dict_ = {}
count = get_count(url.format(0))


def update_rep(iter_):
    for rep in iter_:
        if rep in dict_:
            dict_[rep] += 1
        else:
            dict_[rep] = 1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with get_context('spawn').Pool(10) as pool:
        for prep in pool.imap_unordered(get_rep,  [url.format(i) for i in range(1, count + 1)]):
            update_rep(prep)
            for key, value in sorted(list(dict_.items()), reverse=True):
                print(f"{key}: {value}")
            print("\033[H\033[J")
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```